# Error on geotiff coordinate transformation

Tags: c++, qt, gdal, coordinate-transformation, geotiff

Have error and *crash* in an application using GDAL for extracting latitude & longitude from GeoTiff image running it in openSUSE, while it works fine in Ubuntu for my colleagues. Errors are different for gdal-v3 and gdal-v2 versions, however seems problem is in `OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation` object creation: returns `NULL` in both cases. See details below:

---

#### Code:

```
QGeoCoordinate toGeoCoordinate(double* adGeotransform, OGRSpatialReference& srcRef, int x, int y)
{
    double worldX = adGeotransform[0] + x * adGeotransform[1] + y * adGeotransform[2];
    double worldY = adGeotransform[3] + x * adGeotransform[4] + y * adGeotransform[5];

    OGRSpatialReference dstRef;
    dstRef.importFromEPSG(4326);
    QScopedPointer<OGRCoordinateTransformation> coordinateTransform(
                OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation(&srcRef, &dstRef));
    coordinateTransform->Transform(1, &worldX, &worldY);
    return QGeoCoordinate(worldY,   // lat
                          worldX);  // lon
}

QGeoRectangle extractCoordinate(const QString& path) 
{
    GDALAllRegister();
    GDALDataset *poDataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen( path.toStdString().c_str(), GA_ReadOnly );
    _height = GDALGetRasterYSize(poDataset);
    _width = GDALGetRasterXSize(poDataset);

    double adGeotransform[6];
    poDataset->GetGeoTransform(adGeotransform);
    OGRSpatialReference srcRef(poDataset->GetProjectionRef());
    QGeoCoordinate _topLeft = toGeoCoordinate(adGeotransform, srcRef, 0, 0);
    QGeoCoordinate _bottomRight = toGeoCoordinate(adGeotransform, srcRef, _width, _height);

    return QGeoRectangle(_topLeft, _bottomRight);
}
```

---

#### GDAL 3 (openSUSE):

- gdal - 3.0.4
- libgeotiff5 - 1.5.1
- libproj19 - 7.0.0
- libgeos - 3.8.0

> ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
>   ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create: unrecognized format / unknown name
>   ERROR 6: Cannot find coordinate operations from `PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 10N",BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],ID["EPSG",4326]],CONVERSION["UTM zone 10N",METHOD["Transverse Mercator",ID["EPSG",9807]],PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8801]],PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-123,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8802]],PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,SCALEUNIT["unity",1],ID["EPSG",8805]],PARAMETER["False easting",500000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8806]],PARAMETER["False northing",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8807]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["easting",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],AXIS["northing",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],ID["EPSG",32610]]' to`'

---

#### GDAL 2 (openSUSE):

- gdal2 - 2.4.2
- libgeotiff5 - 1.5.1
- libproj19 - 7.0.0
- libgeos - 3.8.0

> ERROR 6: Unable to load PROJ.4 library (libproj.so.15), creation of OGRCoordinateTransformation failed.

---

#### Ubuntu 18.03 LTS (works fine):

- libgdal - 2.2.3
- libgeotiff - 1.4.2
- libproj12 - 4.9.3

---

So asking for possible solutions:

1. What the errors cause could be:

   - wrong libraries versions;
   - wrong build flags on openSUSE?
2. GeoTiff could be extracted other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in `PROJ` library version used. For `GDAL v2` need to use `libproj v6`. However required `libgeotiff5` and `libspatialite` built against `libproj19` (`proj v7`) in openSUSE Tumbleweed. So need to

1. Uninstall all recent versions of: `libspatialite`, `geotiff`, `libproj19`, `gdal`.
2. Install `libproj15` for example from this repo [home:rogeroberholtzer](https://software.opensuse.org/ymp/home:rogeroberholtzer/openSUSE_Factory/libproj15.ymp?base=openSUSE%3AFactory&query=libproj15)
3. Rebuild `libspatialite` & `geotiff` libraries from `src.rpm` against this installed `libproj15` ourselves:

   ```
   rpmbuild --rebuild --clean libspatialite-4.3.0a-15.19.src.rpm
   rpmbuild --rebuild --clean geotiff-1.5.1-31.13.src.rpm
   ```

   These packages could be taken from [science](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?package=gdal2&project=science) repo for example.
4. Install built packages: `rpm -Uvh *`
5. Install `gdal2-2.4.2` rpm from [science](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?package=gdal2&project=science) repo.

And all works! Enjoy! :)